Как поменять шрифт в кнопке Tkinter?
Как поменять шрифт в кнопке Tkinter. Шрифт Ubuntu. Работаю на Ubuntu
Пробовал
from tkinter import *
import os
root=Tk()
button=Button(text="Restart", command=lambda: os.system("reboot"), font="Ubuntu 14").pack()
root.mainloop() 

Не работает

font принимает кортеж (название, размер, стиль) -> ("", 0, "")

font=("Times New Roman", 14, "italic")
font=("Times New Roman",)
font=font.Font(family= "Arial", size=11, weight="normal", slant="roman", underline=True, overstrike=True)
Или через метод .config -> button.config(font=("Times New Roman", 14, "italic"))

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font

root = tk.Tk()
font1 = font.Font(family= "Arial", size=11, weight="normal", slant="roman", underline=True, overstrike=True)

button1 = tk.Button(
    root, 
    text="button1", 
    font=("Times New Roman", 14, "italic")
)

button2 = tk.Button(
    root, 
    text="button2", 
)

button3 = tk.Button(
    root, 
    text="button3", 
    font=font1
)

button1.pack()
button2.pack()
button2.config(font=("calibri", 9, "italic"))
button3.pack()

root.mainloop()


